# Type '()' cannot conform to 'View' - SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I recently started a beginner project and I have this annoying error. Basically I want to loop trough some tasks, take every progress and sum it.

```
 import Foundation
    import SwiftUI
    
    class sums: ObservableObject{
        @Published var sum: Double = 0
        @EnvironmentObject var listViewModel: ListViewModel
        
        func sums2()->Double{
            ForEach(listViewModel.items){item in
                sum += item.test
            }
            return sum
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is not that ForEach, it is a view container  for views, use `for in`, or reduce, or .forEach, etc.

Answer (score 2):

`ForEach` is a SwiftUI view designed for looping through a collection of objects, and then rendering SwiftUI views for each of them.

What your code seems to be looking for is looping through an array, and adding up a value from each. This is a function for your data rather than your UI, and can be achieved using pure Swift.

Swift offers a couple of looping options: `for...in` and `.forEach`. The former is useful for cases where you might need to skip options or exit a loop early; with `.forEach` you always access every element of the collection. For your case, `.forEach` fits the bill.

```swift
let sum = 0
listViewModel.items.forEach { item in 
  sum += item.test
}
return sum
```

In terms of general programming, I'm not quite sure why you declare `sum` as a property and then have a function which updates that property as well as returning a value. It feels like you're mixing the concepts of view models, helper methods and views in ways that are going to get you in all sorts of trouble.

Depending on how your view model is set up, it might be easier to declare a method within that to handle the summation:

```
class ListViewModel: ObservableObject {
  @Published var items: ItemType

  func sum() -> Double {
    let sum = 0
    items.forEach { sum += $0.test }
    return sum
  }
}
```

The pattern of "loop through a collection and return a single value based on all of them" is such a common one that we have a Swift function, `reduce`, that helps us:

```swift
func sum() -> Double {
  items.reduce(0) { (accumulator, item) in 
    accumulator + item.test
  }
  // or in shorthand
  items.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.test }
}
```

Good luck with the rest of your learning, and remember to keep your **views** separate from your **data**!